# Rails 3 : Heroku app using myapp.herokuapp.com as base for URL building

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url, heroku

I just deployed one of my apps to heroku. This app uses :

- A default **"myapp.herokuapp.com"** address,
- And I got a domain configured so that the app can be reached through **"www.myapp.com"**.

And I noticed today the following issue : my application links are based on  *"http://myapp.herokuapp.com"* domain (hence I get *"http://myapp.herokuapp.com/page"* URLs) even when I access the app using my domain name (I would then expect to get *"www.myapp.com/page"* URLs).

**I tried to edit my production.rb and set the default_url_options :**

```
# Base domain for url generation 
config.action_controller.default_url_options = { :host => "www.myapp.com" }
```

But it doesn't change a thing. Also tried to change this in application.rb, just in case, but nothing happens either.

Any clue ?
Thanks a lot for your help guys !

*Edit : This used to work as expected before today when I did the database migration to the new Heroku postgres thing. Don't know if this can have any impact.*

Comment: Default rails would use the domain you accessed on, are you using some kind of page/fragment caching which could have cached the herokuapp.com links?

Comment: @JohnBeynon, thanks for your suggestion. Didn't think of this but I'm not using any kind of caching anyway.

Comment: so the code for your links, are you using `_path` or `_url`?

Comment: `_path` for my links. Is that what you meant by caching ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using _path methods for your urls, this is generating a relative path which is always based on the url you visit. If you're using controller/fragment caching, you should probably use _url instead in your views. You might also want to consider setting config.action_controller.perform_caching to false in your production.rb if all your pages have some controller logic.

See [this page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) for more info on how caching works in Rails.

Comment: Mmh, don't really manage to understand why using _path used to work and doesn't work anymore. Anyway, I replaced my "visible" links by their _url equivalent, and I'm then presented with the links in the format I was looking for. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. It was caused by the following line of code which was pointing to heroku.com and getting redirected to herokuapp.com

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'my-staging-domain.heroku.com' }
```

I mention it because it's the **action_mailer**.default_url_options yet clearly it affects the default url options outside of the scope of the mailer if you haven't explicitly set up the action_controller.default_url_options